# Paginate one page with different tabs Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, web-frontend

I want to paginate in a blade file different tabs , each tabs show different collections of object but each time i go to next page in one page it redirects to the first tab and also paginate each tab not just the one i wanted to paginate.

**Blade Part Where i have tabs**

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="section-bg-color">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <!-- My Account Page Start -->
                    <div class="myaccount-page-wrapper">
                        <!-- My Account Tab Menu Start -->
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4">
                                <div class="myaccount-tab-menu nav" role="tablist" id="myTab">
                                    <a href="#dashboad" class="active" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i>Dashboard</a>
                                    <a href="#users" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-user"></i>Gestione Utenti</a>
                                    <a href="#comics" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-book"></i>Gestione Fumetti</a>
                                    <a href="#reviews" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>Gestione Recensione</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <!-- My Account Tab Menu End -->
                            <!-- My Account Tab Content Start -->
                            <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-8">
                                <div class="tab-content" id="myaccountContent">
                                    <!-- Single Tab Content Start -->
                                    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="dashboad" role="tabpanel">
                                        <div class="myaccount-content">
                                            <h5>Dashboard</h5>
                                            <div class="welcome">
                                                <p>Ciao, <strong>{{ $user->username }}</strong>! (Non sei <strong>{{ $user->username }}</strong>?<a href="{{ url('/logout') }}" class="logout"> Logout</a>)</p>
                                            </div>
                                            <p class="mb-0">I tuoi dati:</p>
                                            <p class="mb-0">E-mail:   <strong>{{ $user->email }} </strong></p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="myaccount-content">
                                            @php
                                                $notifications = \App\Http\Controllers\NotificationController::getNotification($user->id);
                                            @endphp
                                            <h5>Notifiche</h5>
                                            @if($notifications->count() < 1)
                                                <div class="myaccount-content">
                                                    <h5>Non ci sono ancora notifiche</h5>
                                                </div>
                                            @else
                                                <div class="myaccount-table table-responsive text-center">
                                                    <table class="table table-bordered">
                                                        <thead class="thead-light">
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <th>Data</th>
                                                            <th>testo</th>
                                                            <th>stato</th>
                                                            <th>Action</th>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        </thead>
                                                        <tbody>
                                                        @foreach($notifications as $notification)
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td>{{ $notification->date }}</td>
                                                                <td>
                                                                    @if(strlen($notification->notification_text) > 50 )
                                                                        @php
                                                                            $subnotification = substr($notification->notification_text, 0, 50)
                                                                        @endphp
                                                                        {{ $subnotification }}...
                                                                    @else
                                                                        {{ $notification->notification_text }}
                                                                    @endif
                                                                </td>
                                                                @if($notification->state == 1)
                                                                    <td>
                                                                        Letto
                                                                    </td>
                                                                    <td>
                                                                        <a href="{{ url('/accountArea') }}" class="btn btn-sqr">View</a>
                                                                    </td>
                                                                @else
                                                                    <td>
                                                                        Non letto
                                                                    </td>
                                                                    <td>
                                                                        <a href="{{ route('notificaLetta', ['id' => $notification->id]) }}" class="btn btn-sqr">View</a>
                                                                    </td>
                                                                @endif
                                                            </tr>
                                                        @endforeach
                                                        </tbody>
                                                    </table>
                                                </div>
                                            @endif
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- Single Tab Content End -->
                                @if(session('message'))
                                    {{session('message')}}
                                @endif
                                    <!-- Single Tab Content Start -->
                                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="users" role="tabpanel">
                                        <div class="myaccount-content">
                                            <h5>Utenti</h5>
                                            <div class="myaccount-table table-responsive text-center">
                                                <table class="table table-bordered">
                                                    <thead class="thead-light">
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <th>Nickname</th>
                                                        <th>Phone</th>
                                                        <th>Email</th>
                                                        <th>Tipologia</th>
                                                        <th>Elimina</th>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    </thead>
                                                    <tbody>
                                                    @foreach($users as $user)
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>{{$user->username}}</td>
                                                        <td>{{$user->phone_number}}</td>
                                                        <td>{{$user->email}}</td>
                                                        @if($user->hasGroup('il gruppo degli utenti'))
                                                        <td>Utente</td>
                                                        @else
                                                            <td>Venditore</td>
                                                        @endif
                                                        <td><a class="btn btn-danger" onclick="return myFunction();"  href="{{route('user-delete', $user->id)}}"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a></td>
                                                        <script>
                                                            function myFunction() {
                                                                if(!confirm("Sei sicuro di voler eliminare questo utente"))
                                                                    event.preventDefault();
                                                            }
                                                        </script>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    @endforeach
                                                    {{ $users->links() }}
                                                    </tbody>

                                                </table>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- Single Tab Content End -->



                                    <!-- Single Tab Content Start -->
                                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="comics" role="tabpanel">
                                        <div class="myaccount-content">
                                            <h5>Fumetti</h5>
                                            <div class="myaccount-table table-responsive text-center">
                                                <table class="table table-bordered">
                                                    <thead class="thead-dark">
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <th>Titolo</th>
                                                        <th>ISBN</th>
                                                        <th>Quantità</th>
                                                        <th>Utente</th>
                                                        <th>Elimina</th>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    </thead>
                                                    <tbody>
                                                    @foreach($comics as $comic)
                                                        @php
                                                            $userNeed = App\User::where('id','=',$comic->user_id)->first();
                                                        @endphp
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td>{{$comic->comic_name}}</td>
                                                            <td>{{$comic->ISBN}}</td>
                                                            <td>{{$comic->quantity}}</td>
                                                            <td>{{$userNeed->username}}</td>
                                                            <td><a class="btn btn-danger" onclick="return myFunction();"  href="{{route('comic-delete', $comic->id)}}"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a></td>
                                                            <script>
                                                                function myFunction() {
                                                                    if(!confirm("Sei sicuro di voler eliminare questo fumetto"))
                                                                        event.preventDefault();
                                                                }
                                                            </script>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    @endforeach
                                                    {{ $comics->links() }}
                                                    </tbody>
                                                </table>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- Single Tab Content End -->

                                    <!-- Single Tab Content Start -->
                                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="reviews" role="tabpanel">
                                        <div class="myaccount-content">
                                            <h5>Recensione</h5>
                                            <div class="myaccount-table table-responsive text-center">
                                                <table class="table table-bordered">
                                                    <thead class="thead-dark">
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <th>Titolo</th>
                                                        <th>Fumetto</th>
                                                        <th>Recensore</th>
                                                        <th>Elimina</th>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    </thead>
                                                    <tbody>
                                                    @foreach($reviews as $review)
                                                        @php
                                                            $userReview = App\User::where('id','=',$review->user_id)->first();
                                                            $comicReview = App\Comic::where('id','=',$review->comic_id)->first();
                                                        @endphp
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td>{{$review->review_title}}</td>
                                                            <td>{{$comicReview->comic_name}}</td>
                                                            <td>{{$userReview->username}}</td>
                                                            <td><a class="btn btn-danger" onclick="return myFunction();"  href="{{route('review-delete-local', $review->id)}}"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a></td>
                                                            <script>
                                                                function myFunction() {
                                                                    if(!confirm("Sei sicuro di voler eliminare questa recensione"))
                                                                        event.preventDefault();
                                                                }
                                                            </script>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    @endforeach
                                                    {{ $reviews->links() }}
                                                    </tbody>
                                                </table>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div> <!-- My Account Tab Content End -->
                        </div>
                    </div> <!-- My Account Page End -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is my route
**Route**

```
Route::get('/adminArea', function () {
    $user = \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::user();
    $users = \App\User::where('username','!=','admin')->orderBy('username', 'asc')->paginate(12);
    $comics =Comic::orderBy('comic_name', 'asc')->paginate(12);
    $reviews = \App\Review::orderBy('review_title', 'asc')->paginate(12);
    return view('adminPanel')
        ->with(compact('user'))
        ->with(compact('users'))
        ->with(compact('comics'))
        ->with(compact('reviews'));
})->name('AdminAccount');
```

In the end what i want to do is to paginate each tab differently meaning if a put the next on the comics i don't want to show also in the user tab the second page of user. The problem is that it use the same pagination url for each tabs so i was wondering if the solution is to give each tab an indipendent url

Comment: You want to open new tab when click on pagination link?

Comment: When i click next on the pagination link i want to open the same page with the same tab open with the next paginate page of that tab. The problem is that on pagination reload it goes to the active page (the dasbord in the code) and the pagination takes effects on the other tabs to. I want to paginate just that specific tab

Comment: Then you need to do it with ajax. Go for `Datatables` this will help you. There is most  package `yajra/laravel-datatables` on github. You can try this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It redirects to the first tab because you use javascript tabs with `active` class added to first tab. To resolve problem with tabs you need to change for each tabs nav to: 
`<a href="#dashboad" class="{{ (Route::currentRouteName() == 'YOUR-ROUTE-NAME) ? 'active' : '' }}"` ...

Also here:
`<!-- Single Tab Content Start -->
<div class="tab-pane fade show {{ (Route::currentRouteName() == 'YOUR-ROUTE-NAME) ? 'active' : '' }}"`...

But your problems with paginations will remain.
Here are 2 solutions:

1. Use JS tabs and get data via Ajax request.
2. Use 4 separated routes for each collection and add routes to tabs corresponding above example.

I hope it was clear.

Comment: <a href="#dashboad" class="{{ (Route::currentRouteName() == 'YOUR-ROUTE-NAME) ? 'active' : '' }}" what this code do exactly?

Comment: I show you how to make your tabs be active depending by your browser URL.
This code `{{ (Route::currentRouteName() == 'YOUR-ROUTE-NAME) ? 'active' : '' }}` mean to show active string if current browser route name is equal with "YOUR-ROUTE-NAME", route that define your button.
Eg: `<a href="#dashboad" class="{{ (Route::currentRouteName() == 'dashboard') ? 'active' : '' }}" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i>Dashboard</a>`, but you need to define route with name "dashboard".

Comment: ok so for the 2 solution i have to create 4 separate route , one for each currentRouteName()=='myroutename' and send to them just collection to paginate ?

Comment: Anyway the solution you provided just let me see empy page with no tab selected at the moment when i reload or i do next page

Answer (score 0):

Solution look like this.

Navigation code:

```
<div class="myaccount-tab-menu nav" role="tablist" id="myTab">
  <a href="#dashboad" class="{{ (Route::currentRouteName() == 'dashboard') ? 'active' : '' }}" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i>Dashboard</a>
  <a href="#users" class="{{ (Route::currentRouteName() == 'users') ? 'active' : '' }}" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-user"></i>Gestione Utenti</a>
  <a href="#comics" class="{{ (Route::currentRouteName() == 'comics') ? 'active' : '' }}" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-book"></i>Gestione Fumetti</a>
  <a href="#reviews" class="{{ (Route::currentRouteName() == 'reviews') ? 'active' : '' }}" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>Gestione Recensione</a>
</div>
```

Also for each tab add, don't forget to change route name for each:

```
<!-- Single Tab Content Start -->
<div class="tab-pane fade show {{ (Route::currentRouteName() == 'dashboard') ? 'active' : '' }}" id="dashboad" role="tabpanel">
```

Route code:

```
Route::get('/dashboard', function () {
    $user = \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::user();
    return view('adminPanel')->with(compact('user'));
})->name('dashboard'); 

Route::get('/users', function () {
    $users = \App\User::where('username','!=','admin')->orderBy('username', 'asc')->paginate(12);
    return view('adminPanel')->with(compact('users'));
})->name('users'); 

Route::get('/comics', function () {
    $comics =Comic::orderBy('comic_name', 'asc')->paginate(12);
    return view('adminPanel')->with(compact('comics'));
})->name('comics'); 

Route::get('/reviews', function () {
    $reviews = \App\Review::orderBy('review_title', 'asc')->paginate(12);
    return view('adminPanel')->with(compact('reviews'));
})->name('reviews');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it works!!! Anyway i also changed the href in `<div class="myaccount-tab-menu nav" ` and removed data-toggle to make full working as i wanted (each time you click on a tab it loads another url)